# Sure that the iTunesArtwork file is not required for apps only being sold on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

This [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) says:

> Apps being distributed via ad-hoc distribution may also include a 512
>   x 512 pixel version of their icon in the CFBundleIcons key. The name
>   of this file must be iTunesArtwork and not have a filename extension.
>   The high resolution version of this icon should be 1024 x 1024 pixels
>   and have the name iTunesArtwork@2x. Do not include this icon in your
>   app bundle if you are not distributing your app via ad-hoc
>   distribution.

I am baffled because I have always believed Apple rejects apps that don't include this file. And in iTunes you see a very big app icon. It must be this file. Or not? So regardless of what this document says, it should get included in the bundle?

Comment: it is **may** and in **ad-hoc** distribution. So neither **must** nor the typical iTunes store distribution.

Comment: For Ad-Hoc distribution why you are worrying about Apple's rejection?

Comment: In other words there is no penalty involved when leaving it out? By that I mean Apple still features apps that lack this file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do not include this icon in your app bundle if you are not
>   distributing your app via ad-hoc distribution.

What that says.  Don't include it.

An iTunesArtwork file is an optional file in the app bundle that only has any value in Ad Hoc distributions.  The file is completely unused and unneeded for App Store builds and submissions.

Artwork for the iOS App Store instead has to be submitted via Apple's iTunes Connect web site, seperately from the app.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** There is a contradicting information about iTunesArtwork in various Apple documents. But it seems that file is only needed in AdHoc installations.

I agree to @hotpaw2 - it seems that apps released to App Store does not need to include iTunesArtwork files. But I wanted to add that i[OS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) says the opposite. Below is the quote from the doc with my emphasis.

> Create a large version of your app icon for display in the App Store. Although it’s important that this version be instantly recognizable as your app icon, it can be subtly richer and more detailed. There are no visual effects added to this version of your app icon.
>
> As shown in Table 41-1, the large version of your app icon should
> measure 1024 x 1024 pixels **and be named iTunesArtwork@2x**. (If
> necessary to support some @1x devices, create a version that measures
> 512 x 512 pixels and name it iTunesArtwork.)
>
> NOTE
>
> iOS might also use the large image in other ways. In an iPad app, for
> example, iOS uses the large image to generate the large document icon.
>
> If you’re developing an app for ad-hoc distribution (that is, to be
> distributed in-house only, not through the App Store), you must **also**
> provide the large versions of your app icon. This icon identifies your
> app in iTunes.

This implies that iTunesArtwork is necessary also for AppStore apps, which wrong and can be confirmed as such by other documents. The link that @iamjustaprogrammer provided doesn't work anymore, but here is a link to [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW12), that says it clearly:

> If you are distributing your app ad hoc, include a 512 x 512 pixel
> version of your app icon. This icon is normally provided by the App
> Store from the materials you submit to iTunes Connect. However,
> because apps distributed ad hoc do not go through the App Store, your
> icon must be present in your app bundle instead. iTunes uses this icon
> to represent your app. (The file you specify should be the same one
> you would have submitted to the App Store, if you were distributing
> your app that way.) The filename of this icon must be iTunesArtwork
> and must not include a filename extension. This file is required for
> ad hoc distribution but is optional otherwise.

BTW - if you'll follow the HIG and will name your large image file as iTunesArtwork@2x and try to upload it to iTunesConnect, it won't be accepted, because file extension is expected there (while this file should be named exactly that - without extension - for Ad Hoc distribution).